# how to remove "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' "?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a python learner. I'm trying to find a retirement funds simulator that takes three arguments: a salary (`salary`), a percentage of your salary to save (`save`), and a list of annual growth percentages on investments (`growthRates`). The length of the last argument defines the 
number of years you plan to work; `growthRates[0]` is the growth rate of the first year, `growthRates[1]` is the growth rate of the second year, etc.
on running program I'm having this error:

```
    TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

The code I've written is:

```
    def ret_fund():
        a = int(input("Enter Salary: "))
        b = int(input("Enter Saving Percentage: "))
        c = list(input("Enter List of Growth Rates per Year (must be zero for first year): "))
        ans_list=[]
        x = 1
        global x
        for i in c:
            float(i)
            x = x*(1+0.01*i)+(a*b*0.01)
            ans_list.append(x)
        print (ans_list)
```

I just can't figure out the error. Help me with that please.
what about variable `c`? it doesn't actually take a `list` as an input as demanded by the program. I have to enter numbers like `05643` and they get picked one by one. what if I want to give input like `[0, 5, 6, 4, 3]`?

Comment: you should indicate what line is throwing the error or to post the complete traceback.

Comment: also, what is the exact input on which it fails?

Comment: you probably have a problem with the entered variables. Use print to check if c is what you expect should be

Comment: what about variable c? it doesn't actually take a "list" as an input as demanded by the program. i have to enter numbers like 05643 and they get picked one by one. what if want to give input like [0, 5, 6, 4, 3]?????

Answer (score 2):

The statement `float(i)` does nothing. Either use `i=float(i)`, or substitute `i` in your formula with `float(i)`, since it appears only once.

Depending on what the user enters, `input()` will return a corresponding object. If you enter `0.0, 1.0, 2e10, 99` you already get a tuple of float and integer values, so there is no reason to convert anything, because, for example, `0.01*x` will be converted to floating point in any case. Example:

```
>>> a=input("enter numbers: ")
enter numbers: 1,2,3.0, 5e-10,   99
>>> print type(a), repr(a)
<type 'tuple'> (1, 2, 3.0, 5e-10, 99)
>>> for i in a: print i, type(i)
... 
1 <type 'int'>
2 <type 'int'>
3.0 <type 'float'>
5e-10 <type 'float'>
99 <type 'int'>
>>> for i in a: print 0.01*i, type(0.01*i)
... 
0.01 <type 'float'>
0.02 <type 'float'>
0.03 <type 'float'>
5e-12 <type 'float'>
0.99 <type 'float'>
```

Comment: what about variable c? it doesn't actually take a "list" as an input as demanded by the program. i have to enter numbers like 05643 and they get picked one by one. what if want to give input like [0, 5, 6, 4, 3]?????

Comment: You can simply type `0, 5, 6, 4, 3` on your input prompt, and c will be a list of integer values. You don't even need the enclosing `list( ... )`, just use the returned tuple.

Comment: Please also note that using input() is a serious security risk, since the interpreter applies the eval() function to the string the user enters, making it possible to call any function avaiable form the current namespace with any argumnents. Much better to use raw_input() and split it up yourself. In Python 3, input() no longer evaluates what the user types, and raw_input() is gone.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the `global x`, which overrides the local assignment of `x`. I'm assuming the global `x` is a list of some kind.

**Edit:** A previous version of this answer contained incorrect code for reading the growth rates.

To read a list of growth rates you should read it as a single string, split the string, and convert each piece. The `input` method doesn't do the right thing on its own.

```
c = raw_input("Enter List of Growth Rates per Year (must be zero for first year): ")
for i in c.split():
    i=float(i)
```